# How to scroll the whole layout which have 3 listviews in single layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview

I have tried many methods to display 3 listviews and i can scroll the whole layout.But nothing gets to work.Please give me a solution`

```
<!-- 1 -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/headerheight" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Notifications"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/tv18_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/list_progress"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_dimen"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_small"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_header">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_requests_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_friendreqsts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5 Friend Requests" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_requests_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_friendreqsts_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

`

Comment: read para 2 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html before having listview inside scrollview

Comment: i want to show the 3 lists at a time.then what should i do...?

Comment: i suggest you reconsider your design

Comment: @Raghunandan last two days i'm working on it.Still its not working.If we give weight it will work fine.But for my requiremnt that is not the proper way.